# Is the 'nameList' variable an instance variable or class variable? Why is it not included in the 'synchronised(this){}" statement?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I'm new to Java and is trying to learn the concept of the synchronised statement. The code and statements below came from [Java tutorial Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html).

My question is, is the 'nameList' variable an instance variable or class variable? Why is it not included in the `synchronised(this){}` statement? I'm having great difficulty understanding the concept.

> Synchronized Statements
>
> Another way to create synchronized code is with synchronized
>   statements. Unlike synchronized methods, synchronized statements must
>   specify the object that provides the intrinsic lock:
>
> ```
> public void addName(String name) {
>     synchronized(this) {
>         lastName = name;
>         nameCount++;
>     }
>     nameList.add(name);
> }
> ```
>
> In this example, the addName method needs to synchronize changes to
>   lastName and nameCount, but also needs to avoid synchronizing
>   invocations of other objects' methods. (Invoking other objects'
>   methods from synchronized code can create problems that are described
>   in the section on Liveness.) Without synchronized statements, there
>   would have to be a separate, unsynchronized method for the sole
>   purpose of invoking nameList.add.

Comment: Did you read the "section on Liveness"?

Comment: It does not really say what `nameList` is, but presumably the call does not need external synchronization. The point of this tutorial is to introduce the `synchronized(monitor){}` syntax, which allows to exclude parts of the method from synchronization (or to synchronize on something other than `this`). So they just present this as a case where you have some parts of the methods that should not be covered by the lock (to avoid liveness issues).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is the 'nameList' variable an instance variable or class variable?

You don't really need to know. It's irrelevant.

> Why is it not included in the 'synchronised(this){}" statement?

Because it must be assumed that nameList.add() is already thread-safe, and that the addition of the name to the list doesn't need to be made in the same atomic section as the other two instructions.

But I agree that this is quite a poor example.

Here's a simpler one that is hopefully clearer:

```
public void addName(String name) {
    synchronized(this) {
        lastName = name;
        nameCount++;
    }
    System.out.println("a name has been added");
}
```

You want the two first instructions to be executed atomically. But you don't care that the logging instruction happens after this atomic operation. And you'd like to avoid preventing other threads from acquiring the lock while executing the logging instruction. The synchronized block is thus useful: it makes the critical section as short as possible. Making the method synchronized would make the critical section larger than necessary.